# Something like Mathematica2Latex

Tags: latex

I'm starting to learn about Latex, but I'm at a very basic stage.

I tried a first test. Export a very simple graphic to a TEX file:

```
c1 = {Thickness[0.01], Red, Circle[{0, 0}, 5]};
l1 = {Thickness[0.005], Green, Line[{{0, 0}, {3, 4}}]};
rec1 = {Thickness[0.005], EdgeForm[Black], LightGray, 
   Rectangle[{-3, -4}, {3, 4}]};
Export["C:\\Users\\Leandro\\Documents\\Arquivos TEX\\Imagem.tex", 
 Graphics[{c1, rec1, l1}]]
```

[image]

The code of the generated file was this:

```
%% AMS-LaTeX Created with the Wolfram Language : www.wolfram.com

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, graphics, setspace}

\newcommand{\mathsym}[1]{{}}
\newcommand{\unicode}[1]{{}}

\newcounter{mathematicapage}
\begin{document}

\includegraphics{Imagem_gr1.eps}

\end{document}
```

We can see that along with the `.tex` file, another `.eps` file was created, which is my vector image.

I read in other pages about something like Mathematica2Latex, but the question was forgotten and did not advance. Is there any news in this regard?

Because I was thinking that the output would create the code according to the Tikz commands or another package.

I looked for more information on the websites and found MaTex. Could this be a solution?

Comment: What exactly is your question?  This is the only question on the site mentioning "Mathematica2Latex".

Comment: LaTeX is a text-editor and its source-files are the text files with commands and text data which will be interpreted by compiler to build the final pdf-document. Any graphics inside the final document have to be included into TeX-file as external graphical file (EPS or PDF usually). Additional possibility to create an image in LaTeX is using postscript commands directly. But this is very tricky way.. for true fanatics.
Mathematica made the .tex file for you and the EPS with your graphics.