# Tools that can convert mathematica images into tikz or pgf code to import to latex?

Tags: graphics, formatting, latex

I have learned about **Mathematica2latex** from some websites, I don't know where to download it and how to use. Is there any other tools that can convert mathematica images into tikz or pgf code to import to latex?

Comment: Ditto: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/148346/something-like-mathematica2latex, https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/151567/how-to-call-mathematica-from-rm-latex

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thank you